# TDA2009A speakers making a ticking noise

Tags: integrated-circuit, speakers

I've bought a brand new TDA2009A IC in my local electronics store and all the extra components needed from the schematic, which is provided work this post.
If I connect a speaker (8 ohm, about 10W) to the right input or the left input, the sound is just great. I'm running the IC @ 8V. But when I connect another speaker (the same as the first one) to the other output (either right or left), one of the speakers starts a weird ticking noise on the bass speaker.
I've built this according to the schematic provided in the images, but I've changed the capacitor connected to VCC and GND at pin 9 of the IC to 3300 uF and 220uF with no change (I've done this because of my lack of capacitors at home).
Is there any way to stop the weird ticking?

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSWqJsfmkEE

You can see there, that if I reconnect the speaker to the other output, it still doesn't tick.

[image]

Comment: "Brand new" in the sense of "so old, although still sellable, the manufacturer has declared it obsolete"

Comment: I do personnally know the seller and he sells a lot of these every day, so he has to buy new one like every week or so. They are really brand new.

Comment: Some larger seller has a large stock of them. St doesn't even list then on their products page. They probably haven't been produced in the last 15 years, really. More likely not even in the last 25 years. The datasheet looks like it's from the mid-80s, at the very least.

Answer (score 4):

I just noticed: In your video, the power supply is set to 7.8V.

The chip needs something between 8 and 28 V to work properly.

So you're simply operating out of the specifications of that IC.

Increase the voltage to at least 10V. Use proper (read: much thicker than what you're currently using) wires for power supply.

Again, the IC is positively *ancient*. It doesn't have any undervoltage detection, so it's no surprise that

> When I start about @ 2.3V, the sound is somewhat good, but very quiet. When I bump it up to about 4V, the sound it totally distorted.

since you're practically pushing the sound input through insufficiently biased transistors.

> When I rise it again to about 7V, the sound is really good, but one of the speakers starts to do that tick tick tick...

aligns very nicely with that.

> When I connect both speakers to one channel, even at bigger volumes, it goes just fine.

Yeah, then you reduce the load impedance, and thus, the voltages that the transistors *can* supply get lower, and your sound gets compressed to a smaller voltage range. I'd claim "it goes just fine" is not really true. It might sound like you hit the "loudness" button on an 70's stereo.

I'm still recommending a not-as-obsolete amplifier ICs. There's literally thousands out there which aren't as terrible.

> I do personnally know the seller and he sells a lot of these every day, so he has to buy new one like every week or so.

It's nice that you know your seller personally, but he's selling you ICs that are marked as "obsolete" at digikey, mouser and other larger retailers, and that the original manufacturer (ST) doesn't even list anymore. In other words: he's selling you the crap that no-one but beginners, who don't know better, buy, or people that have to repair ancient amplifiers. Even if DIY audio enthusiast often swear by some older amplifier designs, this IC is simply not worth using in the year 2017. There's nothing comparably good about it.

Go to the website of the former manufacturer of the TDA2009A (it's http://ST.com), click through the audio amplifier ICs and select a [Class AB](http://www.st.com/en/audio-ics/class-ab-audio-power-amplifiers.html?querycriteria=productId=SC979) amplifier (modern class AB will sound a lot better than class B, and be much more efficient than class A, I actually don't find class B in the wild very often anymore; they're basically bad amplifiers, to be honest) and build the schematic from the datasheet. You can often get them for free as samples, or for little money at online retailers.

Don't just buy anything your local seller recommends. He probably has a stock or an extremely cheap source of obsolete parts and is trying to make money with inferior products. That is bad style.

Comment: Well, thank you for your advanced answer, I really appreciate it. I've actually requested the IC from my seller, because I thought that it is some kind of good quality for a low price, as I'm quite a beginner in electronics. Anyway, is it a good idea to find an AB amp on www.ST.com and then buying it from eBay from China?

Comment: No. EBay from China is always a bad idea. Try the usual retailers - mouser, digikey, element14, adafruit...

Answer (score 1):

You're probably just overloading your power supply with two speakers.

You can either get a stronger source of power (more Ampere!), or play your sounds at a lower volume, or get a more effective amplifier.

Or combine any of these measures - especially since the tda2009a has been declared obsolete by the last major manufacturer ST for a while now, it's very likely you'll find better amplifier ICs.

**EDIT** See my other answer. This would apply to the general case, but you specifically undervolt the IC.

Comment: It's a 30W 5A power supply. As I increase the voltage, the ticking goes louder. I don't want to blow up my speakers.

Comment: **decrease** the volume, not increase the voltage.

Comment: And I specifically mentioned Ampere so that you don't increase the volts...

Comment: By the way, thanks for your quick answer :). The amperes are just fine, check out the video. It's running @ about 0.6A and I don't have there any sound source connected. When I connect it, it still does that ticking sound and the music is quite distorted.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention: running both speakers on the same channel works great!

Comment: That sounds like your IC is broken, or still, your single amplifier channel limits the power output, and you don't get supply voltage brownouts. You wouldn't notice this with these low-amperage power cable between your (good) power supply and your IC. You should use an oscilloscope to check whether the supply voltage, **measured close to the IC** is constant.

Comment: Thanks, again. I do not own an oscilloscope. When I start about @ 2.3V, the sound is somewhat good, but very quiet. When I bump it up to about 4V, the sound it totally distorted. When I rise it again to about 7V, the sound is really good, but one of the speakers starts to do that *tick tick tick*... When I connect both speakers to one channel, even at bigger volumes, it goes just fine. The same is true for the other channel. But they kinda won't work together...

Comment: Anyway, I'm going to my local electronics store on Monday and I'll post, if the new IC will do the same or not.

Comment: sounds like insufficient supply stability. Make sure you have thick cabling between supply and IC, lots of capacitors on IC supply, and are operating within IC's voltage range.

Comment: And, don't go back on Monday and buy the same IC again. With the same effort, you can get much better ICs.